# Will visual studio 2015 projects and solutions be backward compatible with 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions, backwards-compatibility, visual-studio-2015, rtm

Now that `Visual Studio 2015 RC` is out, has anyone installed it and opened `Visual Studio 2013` projects/solutions?

- Does it ask the files to be changed?
- If yes, are the changes it makes backward compatible?

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the [Porting, Migrating, and Upgrading Visual Studio Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) article for Visual Studio 2015. All of the various caveats are described there.

Comment: Note that at time of writing, this article has not been fully updated for 2015.

Answer (score 3):

Not all types of project are supported. I tried the following 4 project types:

1. Vb.net Class project, OK.
2. Vb.net Web Services project, OK.
3. Cordova JS project, not OK, need to migrate manually, by moving the sources from root directory to the www directory and install all API again.
4. C#.net winform project, OK.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though you sometimes will have to change the version (single number) in .sln file, no other differences found yet.

We resolved this by typically excluding this file from check in and only check it in when there really was a change (added project, ...) - and then to fix the version before checking in. (Different developer machines with different versions of VS.)

See question [Visual Studio 2015 solutions backwards compatibility with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532477/visual-studio-2015-solutions-backwards-compatibility-with-visual-studio-2013) and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540590/586754.

(Assuming you are having basic projects that are supported by both versions, like C# and .net framework that is supported by lower version VS.)

Comment: After attempting to load in VS2015, my project would not load. It then failed to load also in VS2012. Then, following your advice, I simply changed this line in the csproj file to point to version "11.0", and it loaded in VS2012 again - `<Project ToolsVersion="11.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`