# Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft Fakes and System.Security.Claims.Claim

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-fakes, .net-4.6

I have an interface in a .NET 4.5 (not 4.6) class library,

```cs
public interface IBrokenFakeInterface
{
    Claim WhyWontItGenerateFakeOfThisInterface();
}
```

In my unit test project (MSTest) when I have added the Fakes for the appropriate assembly containing this interface, I get compiler warning that says it cannot generate the stub.

> Warning:  Cannot generate stub for ClassLibrary1.IBrokenFakeInterface:
>   method System.Security.Claims.Claim
>   ClassLibrary1.IBrokenFakeInterface.WhyWontItGenerateFakeOfThisInterface()
>   unstubbable: method is abstract and could not be stubbed, type 
>   System.Security.Claims.Claim is not available in the target framework
>   version. ClassLibrary1Tests   C:\Users\jacobsonba\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects_tempFakeFiguringOut\ClassLibrary1Tests\Fakes\ClassLibrary1.fakes

While this is only a compiler warning, it results in compiler errors when a Unit Test project relies on StubIBrokenFakeInterface, because the Stub concrete type is not being created by the fakes generator.

Does anyone know the cause of this error, and a resolution?
Changing the projects to be .NET 4.6 resolves it, but thats not a reasonable option for these projects for us.  The exact same code compiles just fine in VS2013; in fact, if its compiled with VS2013, then open the solution in VS2015, it continues to work until the Fakes assembly is regenerated.  So its obviously a problem in the fake generator that VS2015 is using.

Comment: I've checked several more ASP.NET web projects of ours (~1000 unit tests per app), and this appears to be the only stub that the VS2015 fakes generator is having a problem with in our code base.  For now, I've implemented a TestDouble class which alleviates the need for this particular stub.  But its still annoying, and no idea if we'll run into other problems.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with Stubs that return MemoryStream. The issue is since Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. We have an issue with ClaimsIdentity and MemoryStream

Comment: Just wanted to follow up; we've encountered no other stubs that had this problem.

Comment: We've encountered the same problem with ClaimsIdentity. Follow up.