# Microsoft Fakes cannot generate stub

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

I have a class library with the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(Claim claim);
}
```

I have a unit test project with the following test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var stubIFoo = new ClassLibrary1.Fakes.StubIFoo();
    }
}
```

If both projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.6 everything works fine. But, if both projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1, I get the following warning:

> Cannot generate stub for ClassLibrary1.IFoo: method System.Void
>   ClassLibrary1.IFoo.Foo(System.Security.Claims.Claim claim)
>   unstubbable: method is abstract and could not be stubbed, type
>   System.Security.Claims.Claim is not available in the target framework
>   version.

And a compilation error because `StubIFoo` is not generated anymore:

> The type or namespace name 'StubIFoo' does not exist in the namespace
>   'ClassLibrary1.Fakes' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is the contents of the `ClassLibrary1.fakes` file:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true" Verbosity="Verbose">
  <Assembly Name="ClassLibrary1"/>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Remove TypeName="IFoo"/>
    <Remove TypeName="IBar"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Do you have any ideea about how can I make this work when both projects target 
.NET Framework 4.5.1 ?

Comment: Same error as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541039/visual-studio-2015-microsoft-fakes-and-system-security-claims-claim