# Using multiple versions of Visual Studio on same code base

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

If a code base (C#) is already being coded under VS2012, can VS2015 also be used on the same code/solution/projects without changing or corrupting it?

thanks!

Comment: It should be able to.  However, there's a very easy way to *test* this.  Open the code in VS2015, make a change, build, test, etc.  Then look at the local changes for source control.  Has anything other than the change you made in the code been modified in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio 2012 C# projects can be opened in VS2015 and vice versa. I have been using both alongside each other for several months.

Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532477/visual-studio-2015-solutions-backwards-compatibility-with-visual-studio-2013) and the [official guide on MSDN to portability and upgrading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). In short, not all project types are supported, but for C# everything is fine.