# How do i upgrade for Visual studio 2010 to the 2015 one

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

Long story short im using visual studio 2010,i would like to install the 2015 one.What is the best way to do this?Unistall everything related to VS 2010 and go with the 2015 one or just download the setup of VS2015 and just install it right away in hope it replaces the old files?!?

NOTE:I dont want to change any code just the application.

Comment: I've always just downloaded and ran the setup for the new one.  I kinda like having the older versions for testing

Comment: Oh,Thanks for the response ill do that since im working on new and old projects.

Comment: ***I dont want to change any code just the application*** BTW, if your application uses external dependencies make sure all of the dependencies are built with the new compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run both versions side by side.  I currently have 2008, 2012, 2013, and 2015 all installed on my PC.

Comment: Thank you.ill do the same :p.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different version (or more) of Visual Studio installed.

The top of the solution file says which version it was built with - but you can open a project/solution built with a previous version in a newer version and rebuild it. It will automatically convert the project for you.

You may find some things don't compile of behave slightly differently. Microsoft gives a list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx)

Comment: You might even open and compile a solution (>=VS2010) with a newer Visual Studio. I am currently using a VS2015 instance to program and compile VS2010 programs (compatibility reasons). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31600348/4181011)